# Why does drawRect get called when I set a rotation transform in OSX? Shouldn't this be in hardware?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, calayer

I've noticed a pretty odd difference between how CALayers seem to respond to transforms on OSX and iOS. On iOS if you apply a rotation transform to a UIView drawRect is not called, the view is transformed in hardware and displayed on the screen. On OSX if you apply a rotation transform to a NSView drawRect is called every time. Here is the code for my NSView:

```
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self)
    {
        self.wantsLayer = YES;
        self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawDuringViewResize;
    }

    return self;
}


- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:dirtyRect] fill];
    NSLog(@"inside drawRect");
}
```

My question is why does drawRect get called on OSX but not on iOS? I don't want it to be called during rotation because my draw is expensive.

Comment: So I figured out a partial solution, I can use layer hosting NSViews instead of layer backed NSViews and then drawRect does not get called during the rotation transformation. I'm still not sure why exactly this doesn't happen when I use a layer backed view so if somebody has some insight here I would definitely like to hear it.